# HLSL - Why Can't I Redefine this Array?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, initialization, hlsl, redefinition

```
float myArray[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Why is this not possible to do in HLSL?
Is it some kind of memory issue?

Answer (score 0):

Because the curly braces here is part of the syntax for aggregate initialization.
`{}` alone does not create a new array.
what you can do is

```
float myArray[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
float local[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

myArray = local;
```